# xsd to xml tool with user input

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xml-signature

Can someone suggest me a tool or converter in java which does the following
(1) User will provide XSD file to Tool. 
(2) Tool will interpret XSD and present a screen to allow data entry (as per the types defined in XSD). 
(3) User will enter values and click ‘Generate XML’.
(4) Tool will generate XML with user entered values and that conforms to XSD definition.

Comment: Framemaker used to do this for SGML files. I never found a similar tool for XML. One technology to consider is Xforms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XForms

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) for accessing xml documents.